# Men In Black 1 alternate/different known endings

Tags: story-identification

Watching this ending clip I got weird a feeling, I recalled there's something missing/different.

This is what I remembered:

After the last scene show in this video, camera rolls over zoom out again and there is another bigger alien from this one, (with it kids) playing with more bigger galaxy balls(not marbles) (like playing soccer with it), it has greenish nuance/environment.

I don't remember if that scenes that occurred to my memory are came from MIB 1 or different movie, does anyone know about this?

Is there any chance that there are alternate endings or a 'director cut's' version, or it is simply it just another movie ending similar to Men In Black?

and yes i surely know the ending at MIB 2, but thats not what i'm referring to, this is completely different its not happen in closet/locker.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kL3SGR85ymY

Comment: Nope, not that one, i know the MIB 2 ending in the locker, theres no alien kids with universe ball in it.

Comment: oh my.... my mind was restless, i really wanna know the answer, it start bugging me like itching in the back of elephant

Comment: I'm 99.99% certain that this isn't from any Men in Black film .